# Skip data in Json/Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have an array. Please check example:

```
Users 
{

user {
Name: dd1
Nickname: ddd1
}   
user {
Name: dd2
Nickname: ddd2
}
user {
Name: dd3
Nickname: NULL

}
```

I do some `foreach` for `echo` results of array. But i need skip in `echo` Users with "Nickname"==NULL. Please give me advice how to do that? Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You may use `continue;`

Comment: Adding your code to the question will make answering it a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

foreach ($myarray as $data){

    if($data['Nickname'] == 'NULL'){
        continue;
    }
}
```

This should do the trick. If the nickname field is NULL it will move to the next.

Comment: Glad i helped.  If i helped you solve your problem please mark my answer as accepted.